# How to make confusion matrix to test the model of Conv-neural network in python?

Tags: python, anaconda, conv-neural-network

I have a CNN model for a plant seeds classification problem. I successfully tested my model and now   I am trying to create a confusion matrix for my CNN model in python but I am getting value error. How can I solve this problem?

code fragment for x and y values:

```
  seed = 31
    np.random.seed(seed)    
    # Split the train and the validation set
    x, x_test, y, y_test= train_test_split(train_tensors, train_targets, test_size = 0.3, train_size =0.7)
    x_train, x_cv, y_train, y_cv = train_test_split(x,
                                                  y, 
                                                  test_size=0.15,
                                                  random_state=seed
                                                 )    
    
    print(x_train.shape)
    print(x_cv.shape)
    print(y_train.shape)
    print(y_cv.shape)

def one_hot_to_dense(labels_one_hot):
    num_labels = labels_one_hot.shape[0]
    num_classes = labels_one_hot.shape[1]
    labels_dense = np.where(labels_one_hot == 1)[1]      
    return labels_dense
```

Code fragment where I got error:

```
validation_predictions = model.predict_classes(x_test)
    report=classification_report(one_hot_to_dense(y_test),validation_predictions)
conf_mat= confusion_matrix(one_hot_to_dense(x_test), validation_predictions)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,figsize=(10,10))

ax = sns.heatmap(conf_mat, ax=ax, cmap=plt.cm.BuGn, annot=True)
ax.set_xticklabels(abbreviation)
ax.set_yticklabels(abbreviation)
plt.title('Confusion Matrix')
plt.ylabel('True class')
plt.xlabel('Predicted class')
fig.savefig('Confusion matrix.png', dpi=300)
plt.show();

--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-21-9c8b8af74165> in <module>
----> 1 conf_mat= confusion_matrix(one_hot_to_dense(x_test), validation_predictions)
      2 fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,figsize=(10,10))
      3 
      4 ax = sns.heatmap(conf_mat, ax=ax, cmap=plt.cm.BuGn, annot=True)
      5 ax.set_xticklabels(abbreviation)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py in confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels, sample_weight)
    251 
    252     """
--> 253     y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
    254     if y_type not in ("binary", "multiclass"):
    255         raise ValueError("%s is not supported" % y_type)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py in
_check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
     69     y_pred : array or indicator matrix
     70     """
---> 71     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
     72     type_true = type_of_target(y_true)
     73     type_pred = type_of_target(y_pred)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    203     if len(uniques) > 1:
    204         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 205                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    206 
    207 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 658]
```

Comment: show sample of your testing Y, show sample of your predicted data

Comment: I added the code where I initialized x and y.

Answer (score 0):

Your two lists : one_hot_to_dense(x_test) and validation_predictions don't have the same length. You need to have two arrays with the same length (y_true, y_pred) for this function to work (see [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html))

Comment: So how can I make length of arrays same with each other?

Comment: what is the function one_hot_to_dense ?

Comment: Look at the shape of one_hot_to_dense(x_test) and compare it to validation_predictions shape. I think you loose some values with `labels_dense = np.where(labels_one_hot == 1)[1]` in your one_hot_to_dense function